# StackExchange.Redis HGET/HGETASYNC returns null when hash key is GUID

Tags: c#, .net, redis, .net-4.5, stackexchange.redis

I'm experiencing some issue and I believe it might be a bug in *StackExchange.Redis* library.

When I create a hash where keys are GUID, both `.HashGet` or `HashGetAsync` will return a `null` value, while when I try to get the same hash key using `redis-cli` I'm able to retrieve the hash value successfully.

Comment: Do you have an exact code sample? There is no implicit conversion from `Guid` to `RedisKey`, so I'm intrigued whether this is via a `string` or a `byte[]`, and either way: how exactly you are doing it. I also wonder if you could run `MONITOR` on a separate redis-cli instance to see what the two approaches are issuing.

Comment: @MarcGravell It's string. I'm going to try with `RedisKey` directly and see what happens

Comment: my first guess would be: formatting; capitalization, spacing, hyphens, etc

Comment: @MarcGravell Uhm either with Guid.ToString or Guid.ToByteArray results in null. The code is just something like this: `db.HashGetAsync(string.Format("whatever:licensing:products:{0}:features:{1}:all", productId, featureId), id.ToByteArray())`

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually I'm copy-pasting the key "quick-watching" the result of the `string.format` to `redis-cli` and this way I'm able to get the hash value

Comment: it is quite hard to compare that between the two systems, without knowing what the `string.Format` and `id.ToByteArray()` resolve to, and without comparing those to the equivalent. What is `id` here? I guess what I'm getting at here: there isn't enough information here to let me know if there is even a problem... the `redis-cli` / `monitor` output of X vs Y would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, the guid here seems to be the hash field sub-key. Fundamentally, it works fine; see:

```
static void Main()
{
    int i = new Random().Next();
    Console.WriteLine("> {0}", i);
    Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    using (var muxer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1:6379"))
    {

        var db = muxer.GetDatabase();
        db.KeyDelete("foo");
        db.HashSet("foo", guid.ToByteArray(), i);
    }
    using (var muxer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1:6379"))
    {
        var db = muxer.GetDatabase();
        var val = (int)db.HashGet("foo", guid.ToByteArray());
        Console.WriteLine("< {0}", val);
    }
}
```

which should show the same randomly generated number twice (once as it sets it, once as it fetches it).

I can only assume that this is an expectation failure; for example:

- you are using strings in one place and binary in another (they will not be equal)
- you are using different formatting (case, spacing, hyphens, etc) rules in the two places (they will not be equal)
- you are falling foul of the "crazy endianness" of `Guid.ToByteArray()`, which does **not** output what people usually expect.

You can see this last scenario here:

```
Guid guid = new Guid("00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF");
var arr = guid.ToByteArray();
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10) Console.Write('-');
    Console.Write(arr[i].ToString("X2"));
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

which actually outputs:

```
33221100-5544-7766-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF
```

Note that the first, second and third groups are reversed. If *this* is the problem, then blame [`ToByteArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)! However, I strongly suspect the first two are more likely. To investigate, the best thing to do would be to run `redis-cli` in `monitor` mode while you compare what the two different systems are doing.

Comment: I'm going to put everything together and check if you advises can solve the issue!! Thank you in advance for the effort

Comment: Hey! I'm doing `Guid.ToString()` everywhere. BTW, I believe that actually the issue has more to do with the `RedisKey` rather than the subkey in some hash. I've tried to do the `monitor` thing and it outputs the right command. After all, if I copy-paste the command to `redis-cli` and I execute it, I can retrieve the data!!! It seems that something weird is happening in the library itself, am I wrong?

Comment: OMFG!!!!!!!!!!!! Do you know what was the #@3!!! issue?? In a concrete method I wasn't selecting the right Redis DB!! When I run test I select the `db 1` instead of `0`, and the method which created the keys was correctly pointing to `1` while the one retrieving them was pointing to `0`!!!!!!!! Argh... Well, thank you for your effort...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer hah! Fair enough - "wrong DB" didn't immediately occur to me, but shows the importance of a repeatable sample ;p